# Start Flex paper

Tags: apache-flex

I want to open .swf files in browser for this downloaded Flex paper but some one tell that how i connect file or give file to flex paper or how i start flex paper

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You may want to provide some background info, such as "What is Flex Paper"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend going to the Flex Paper site where there are some quick start guides:
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs.htm

The section "Using FlexPaper in Adobe Flex" gives a very quick application to get you started and explains how to read in a local PDF file.  Note that you'll need to download the relevant library file from the downloads page to get this working.